# Showing line numbers for text in tables

Tags: tables, longtable, lineno

I was under the impression that this should be fairly simple. However,
for texts put directly inside a table, line numbers are not being shown.

Strangely, when texts are generated using `lipsum`, 
line numbers are shown.

Here is the MWE, which should be self explanatory:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Simple Text}

\lipsum[1]

\section{Direct Text in Table}

Line numbers will \textit{not} be shown in the texts in the following table:

\begin{longtable}{l>{\raggedright\internallinenumbers}p{0.20\textwidth}} 
  A&Line numbers are not shown for this text, we need to solve
  this\tabularnewline
\end{longtable}

\section{Text in Table Using \texttt{lipsum}}

Line numbers will be shown in the texts in the following table:

\begin{longtable}{l>{\raggedright\internallinenumbers}p{0.75\textwidth}} 
  A&\lipsum[2]
\end{longtable}

\section{Simple Text Again}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

*(My texts will be input using `csvsimple`, or `datatool`, if that is relevant in any manner.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `\tabularnewline`, use `\par`:

```
\begin{longtable}{l>{\raggedright\internallinenumbers}p{0.20\textwidth}} 
  A&Line numbers are not shown for this text, we need to solve
  this\par
\end{longtable}
```

This yields:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, simple yet effective solution. I would like to add that you need to still put the `\tabularnewline` when there are other columns after the text column.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I would not mind that close proximity since these numbers are purely temporary, used only for editing feedbacks.

Comment: @Masroor OK, btw, +1!